# positioning and resizing the browser window

Tags: css, position, css-position, stylesheet, pixel

Positioning responsively is the most confusing thing to me. Ill give a simple example to help portray what i can't figure out. I have a div. I make the width and height a percentage and position it on the page absolute, top 25% and left 5%. All of this looks fine but when i resize the page it moves to 25% and 5% of that smeller screen resolution, and i can't get it to just stay there. I have a min-width and height so that the actual div won't resize, just where it is positioned on the page. How do i position something on a web page so that it is responsive, yet will no move all over the place when i resize the browser window. Sorry if I'm not really good at explaining this, i just never really understood how to position correctly.

Example :

```
#example_div {
   width: 10%;
   height: 10%;
   min-width: 100px;
   min-height: 100px;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 25%;
   left: 5%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

percentage values are always *relative* to the parent element (i.e. the on around the current element, which can also be the body or window).

pixel values are absolute. You can combine pixel and percentage values. If you want your DIV to shrink when you resize the window, but stay at the same position, use percentage values for width and height, and pixel values for top or bottom and left or right.